# É possível ver o progresso de carregamento da imagem em js?

Tags: javascript, imagem

Tem alguma forma de saber o progresso do carregamento de imagens? Tentei usar `onload` e onprogress conforme sugerido em uma dica anterior, mas apenas `onload` funciona.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    console.log("Carregado");
};

image.onprogress=function(){
    console.log("Em progresso");
};

image.src = imageUrl;
```

Comment: Por que o negativo? Reconheço que em web design normalmente as imagens são e devem ser de carga rápida e por isso um mecanismo desse não faz sentido porém em aplicações gis e aplicações médicas as imagens podem ter tamanhos absurdos e demorarem uma quantidade considerável de tempo para carga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os elementos nativos `<img>`, de interface [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement), embora possua (herdado de `HTMLElement`) propriedades de evento como `onload`, não possuem meios nativos para se mesurar progresso.

Você pode, então, utilizar a API [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) para baixar a imagem e medir o progresso durante esse processo.

Um exemplo bem corriqueiro:

```js
const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544867160-9a42c8d11d40';

loadImgSrc(url, (e) => {
  console.log('Progresso:', e);
}).then((blobUrl) => {
  console.log('Carregada.');
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = blobUrl;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

function loadImgSrc(url, onProgress) {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('GET', url, true);
  req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  
  req.onprogress = function(e) {
    onProgress(e.loaded / e.total, e);
  };
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.onload = function(e) {
      const blob = new Blob([this.response]);
      resolve(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    };
    req.onerror = reject;
    req.send();
  });
}
```

Note que estamos utilizando o evento `progress` (anexado à propriedade `onprogress`) para calcular uma *porcentagem* do progresso. Para isso, dividimos `loaded` por `total`, que são propriedades presentes no primeiro parâmetro (`event`).

Após a imagem ser carregada, utilizamos a [API `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Blob) em conjunto com [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURl) para criar um *blob URI*, que fará referência à imagem já carregada.

Essa implementação foi baseada [nesta pergunta do StackOverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218607/javascript-loading-progress-of-an-image). Consulte-a para verificar diversos outros exemplos.

---

Mas tome cuidado que isso pode acabar complicando as coisas. Geralmente, imagens não são tão pesadas assim e calcular o progresso dessa forma pode acabar sendo um exagero. Na maioria dos casos, o mero `onload` já funciona.

Comment: Só lembrando, existem questões de CORS, no mesmo dominio é ok, fora vai depender das configurações.

Comment: Exatamente! Eu já havia lido essa pergunta, no entanto achei a reposta um pouco confusa, mas com sua explicação, ficou tudo mais simple. Entendo parecer um exagero, até porque eu mesmo acho isso e não entendo o motivo de apenas o `onload ` não estar suprindo as minhas necessidades. Caso sinta interesse em saber o porque fiz essa pergunta, visite esse link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/479957/como-as-imagens-s%c3%a3o-processadas-no-canvas

Comment: Sim sim @GuilhermeNascimento, pode deixar! Obrigado!